# In Java, is there a logical reason why I cannot say "java MyClass.class " from command line?

Tags: java, command-line, program-entry-point

Maybe this question may be splitting hairs, but when I compile a file from command line like :

```
javac MyClass.java
```

then afterward I cannot run it by saying

```
java MyClass.class
```

I have to call:

```
java MyClass
```

What is the motivation for  this notation?

Comment: Because you don't have to type so much...it's also possible that the class loading process automatically appends .class to the name when it does it loading...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Fair enough , so it's just the notation . slightly arbitrary i guess. i think the `java ABC.java` line is what gets sent more often though.

Comment: The class is called `MyClass` not `MyClass.class` The reason you specify the file name for `.java` is that it can contain multiple classes which can have different names.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: you compile a file (not a class contained in a file), and you run a class (not a file that contains that class).

Comment: As far as Java specification is concerned, there is no mention of the `.class` extension, or even the file system as the container of the class files. The `java` command follows that abstract approach to naming your entry-point class. `java` *does* accept `/` for `.`, which kind of surprised me when I found out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you run a class on the classpath, which may be contained inside a jar for example. You couldn't use your syntax in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Java compiler needs a compilation unit; this is by default (at least) a java source file, with the whole of classes defined in it and its dependencies.

Java interpreter (the jvm) needs a single class with a main method as entry point of the execution - it must start somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to ask Sun (now Oracle) for the development history, but I do want to point out that for folks who are just using Java rather than developing Java, "java DoSomething" is easier to remember, and to type, than "java DoSomething.class"

Comment: Java forbids `.` in a class name (it has to part of the path of a class) or `class` being used as it's a keyword. The JVM byte code allows `.` and `class` in names so they could appear as you say.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to run a Java program that is not a class. For that reason, there is no reason to mandate typing the ".class". You might also invoke a class from within a JAR on your path, or directly, but it's still instantiating a class (possibly a "default" class from the Manifest).

Comment: Minor quibble: you can run a Java program directly out of a jar file's "default class", but that does require the -jar option on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Because the name of the class is `MyClass` and not `MyClass.class`. And when running `java` you specify the CLASS NAME and not the PATH to the actual compiled file.
For more in depth knowledge I guess Sun & Oracle will have to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have a class named `package` and you have a class named `Class`, in a package named `package`,

```
--CurrentFolder
    --package
         Class.class
      package.class
```

so executing java `package.class` may lead to an undecidability to the compiler!